# Email address validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, email, dictionary

Update the question

Hello All,

I would like improve my email address validation code. Currently, we have 6 different email address

```
var emailPatt=/@(tomtom|stream|teleperformance|htc.teleperformance).com/i;
var emailPattUS2=/@(teleperformance).com/i;
var emailPattUS3=/@(hispanic).corp/i
var emailPattUS4=/@(htc).to/i
```

As you see, there are 4 variables, when users' email address have emailPatt2, emailPatt3, emailPatt4, it will send to "profil2" page. For emailPatt except "htc.teleperformance.com" will go to profile page

```
// For // Tomtom.com and stream.com email address will redirect to profile page
//Htc.to, Htc.teleperformance.com, Teleperformance.com, Hispanic.corp will go to prolfe2 page. 


else if(emailPattUS2.test(eo.data.username)|| emailPattUS3.test(eo.data.username)|| emailPattUS4.test(eo.data.username)) //If the email is teleperformance.com
            {document.location.href="/app/account/profile2";}
                else
                    {document.location.href="/app/account/profile";}
                },
```

In the main login process code:

```
**// If login's email address is one of these: 
// Tomtom.com
//Stream.com
//Htc.to
//Htc.teleperformance.com
//Teleperformance.com
// Hispanic.corp
// then Login code will fire event (loginFormSubmitRequest) , it will check email address //and password in dataase

if(emailPatt.test(eo.data.username)|| emailPattUS3.test(eo.data.username)||emailPattUS4.test(eo.data.username)) //Search the regualr expres between string
    {
       // alert("test works");
        RightNow.Event.fire("evt_loginFormSubmitRequest", eo);
        new YAHOO.util.Anim("rn_" + this.instanceID + "_Content", { opacity: { to: 0 } }, 0.5, YAHOO.util.Easing.easeOut).animate();
        YAHOO.util.Dom.addClass("rn_" + this.instanceID, 'rn_ContentLoading');

       //since this form is submitted by script, force ie to do auto_complete
        if(YAHOO.env.ua.ie > 0)
        {
        if(window.external && "AutoCompleteSaveForm" in window.external)
        {
            var form = document.getElementById("rn_" + this.instanceID + "_Form");
            if(form)
            window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm(form);
        }
        }
        return false;
    }

// When the email address is not from the list, they will not fire login event. throw
//error message.
//
//
    else if(!emailPatt.test(eo.data.username)|| !emailPattUS3.test(eo.data.username)||!emailPattUS4.test(eo.data.username))
    {
       //alert(emailPatt.test(eo.data.username));
       // alert ("not tomtom email address");
        me._onLoginResponse("evt_loginFormSubmitResponse", [{
        w_id : eo.w_id,
        result : 0,
        message : RightNow.Interface.getMessage('EMAIL_IS_NOT_VALID_MSG')
        }]);
    }

    },
```

That is quit not optimize at all. I am wondering whether there is dictionary list i can use to look though all the email address in here. It will a bit clean and fast for the system .

Thanks

Comment: Both`emailPatt` and `emailPattUS2` match `teleperformance.com`, there is no need for parentheses in `emailPattUS2`, `emailPattUS3` nor `emailPattUS4` since they only have one domain. In your main login code, you have already tested the patterns in the first `if`, therefore it´s enough to do a `else` and no need to do an `if(!...)`. Also the second `if` probably doesn't do what you think since you use the `or` operator instead of `and`.

Comment: hi Some, thanks. In second "if" , i want to check whether login email address has emailpatt, or emailPatt2, emailPatt3 or emailPattUS4. If they have one of them, they will start login process checking. If i use "and", it sounds for me that you need to have all the email address. Am i right in here?

Comment: In the second `if`-statement you use the `invert`-operator. That means that if the email doesn't match the pattern in `emailPatt` the expression is true and no other tests is made. Since you already tested `emailPatt` in the first `if`-statement and you are using `else` before the second statement, it will ALWAYS evaluate to `false` and since you invert it the test will ALWAYS be `true`. Your code doesn't make sense. Please update your question with an explanation in plain English of what you are trying to do and you will get help with the logic.

Comment: hi some, i update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A page about validating email-addresses using regexps http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html